# How can you make a decimal point for a number display on Desmos?

Tags: desmos

I have [this Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/udvuhtixst) which is a number display. You type a button and that number gets displayed. I'm thinking about turning it into a calculator, but first I need a decimal point. (Also the negative function doesn't work, but that's a problem for another time). The way the display works is that I have a slider $a$ for the number being typed. Every subsequent digit $n$ you type, it preforms the action $a\rightarrow10a+n$.

I've tried having a separate slider "$p$" with a step of 1 to represent the place of the decimal point, but I have yet to figure out how to utilise it. The closest thing I've seen for what I'm trying to find is on [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4bawqnc1fh) from a contest in $2020$, but I have absolutely no clue what the heck is going on in there.

I think it should be something along the lines of this: "after the decimal point is placed, every subsequent digit $q$ typed will be divided by [the place of the decimal point times ten] and then added onto the total", but I'm still not entirely sure how I would go about doing that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should I have to program it with a classical programming language, I would use conversion to/from **string** type.

Comment: A personal advice : don't waste too much time building complex programs with Desmos and Geogebra which can be wonderful tools for moderate complexity issues, but soooo difficult to debug beyond a certain size ! Switch to a classical programming language...

Comment: @JeanMarie I doubt that The_Animator is doing the calculator as a practical tool. My guess is that is doing it to see if he/she can do it. That's the point of [several things made in desmos](http://www-evasion.imag.fr/Membres/Fabrice.Neyret/demos/DesmosGraph/indexImages.html) or more generally, in esoteric languages like Brainf*ck, Malbolge or Perl.

Comment: @jjagmath "doing it to see if he/she can do it" Yes, for sure, I agree, like "golf coding"... My point was just to advise a young student to switch to much more efficient/rewarding methods.

Comment: @jjagmath got it spot on. There's no *practical* use for there to make a calculator in Desmos, I'm just doing it to test my abilities, also because I think it's kinda fun to have projects to work on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track on how many decimal places there are, like in [this Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lci0li4xbk) based on yours.  What it does:

- It introduces a new var `d` that keeps track on whether <kbd>.</kbd>  was pressed (`0` or `1`).
- When <kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, then`d → 0`, `p → 0`, and `s → 1`.
- There is a new var `b` that is $b=s\cdot a\cdot 10^{-p}$, and the big black field now displays `b` (formerly `a`).
- On pressing a digit, `p` is incremented by `d`.

Now when you type, say, <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> then `b = 0.12` will hold that value, and it is displayed as such in the big black rectangle.

---

What I don't know how to do is when you press <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> which should display `0.0`, but it will only start to display something other than `0` when you type a non-zero digit. To fix this, one would need strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable `PointPressed` to $0$. When "." is pressed set it to $1$. Set a variable `PowerOfTen` equal to $1$. In the number buttons, when pressed, update `a` in the same way, but also if `PointPressed` is $1$ set `PowerOfTen = PowerOfTen*10`. Instead of displaying `a` in the output, display `a/PowerOfTen`

Comment: Yeah, that does work from a *logical* perspective, but how would I make it so that PowerOfTen only changes if PointPressed is 1 in a program like Desmos?

Comment: I don't know if there is an `if` in the scripting language of desmos , but I know that there is possible to [define piecewise expressions](https://help.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405305421709-Graphing-Calculator-Essential-Skills). A more mathematical way is  `PowerOfTen = PowerOfTen * (10^PointPressed)`